# Excel VBA - Need to get data into next row, and remove from existing place

Tags: vba, excel

On the same worksheet, I'm trying to compact all my cell data, i.e. move all the cells with value to be next to each other instead of spread apart. The original sheet looks like this:
[image: picture 1]

The desired output would be something like this:
[image: picture 2]

I have tried below code to solve this problem, and sorry I'm new here so don't know how to ask the question

```
Sub SelectRangea()

   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("a1:cf1").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy


With Sheets("Sheet1")
   lst = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
   .Range("A" & lst).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
   .Range("A" & lst).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that this is a code writing service, where you post a vague list of requirements and your language of choice, and some code monkey here churns out code to meet them. You're mistaken. We're glad to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. When you've done so and run into difficulty, you can explain the problem you've encountered, post the **relevant portions** of the code you've written, and ask a **specific question** related to that code, and we'll try to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves the problem as per your sample data.

```
Dim c As Long

c = 1
With Worksheets("sheet6")
    c = .Cells(1, c).End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).Column
    Do While c < .Columns.Count
        With .Range(.Cells(1, c), .Cells(1, c).End(xlToRight))
            .Parent.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, .Columns.Count) = .Cells.Value
            .Clear
        End With
        c = .Cells(1, c).End(xlToRight).Column
    Loop
End With
```

If one of the 'islands' of data in the first row is a single cell then you will have to accommodate that special condition.